# Cannot find valid reference

Tags: c, reference

I have a c file for hardware initialization and a c++ file that calls methods from it. When I attempt to compile them using g++, I get the following

```
g++ testPegio.cpp -o testPeg
```

I get the following:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/chrono:35:0,
>                    from testPegio.cpp:6:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.

So I try this:

```
g++ testPegio.cpp -o testPeg -std=c++0x
```

And I get:

> /tmp/cczOOOyb.o: In function `main':
>   testPegio.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to`pegio_init'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Here are the important snippets of code:

pegio.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>     //used for uart
#include <fcntl.h>      //used for uart
#include <termios.h>    //used for uart
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

#define BAUD_RATE B1152000
#define BYTE_SIZE CS8
#define MAX_STRING_LEN 80

#define true 1
#define false 0

typedef int bool;

extern char pegio_init(void);                                       // initialize serial port
extern char pegio_deinit(void);                                     // deinitialize serial port
extern void pegio_serial_write(char inStr[MAX_STRING_LEN]);         // serial write method
extern void pegio_serial_read(char * str);                          // serial read method
extern bool charCheck(char ch);                                     // character check
```

pegio.c

```
#include "pegio.h"

int uart0_filestream = -1;

// ** INITIALIZE THE UART **    
char pegio_init(void)
{

    uart0_filestream = open("/dev/ttyAMA0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (uart0_filestream == -1)
    {
        //ERROR - Can't open serial port
        printf("Error - Unable to open UART. Ensure it is not in use by another application\n");
    }

    struct termios options;
    tcgetattr(uart0_filestream, &options);
    options.c_cflag = BAUD_RATE | BYTE_SIZE | CLOCAL | CREAD;   //<Set the baud rate
    options.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
    options.c_oflag = 0;
    options.c_lflag = 0;
    tcflush(uart0_filestream, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(uart0_filestream, TCSANOW, &options);

    return 0;
}

// ** DEINITIALIZE THE UART **
char pegio_deinit()
{
    close(uart0_filestream);
    return 0;
}
```

And finally, testPeg.cpp

```
extern "C" {
#include "pegio.h"
}

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int result = pegio_init();

        return result;
}
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps,

```
 gcc -c pegio.c -o pegio.o
 g++ testPeg.cpp pegio.o -o testPeg -std=c++0x
```

<strike>g++ testPeg.cpp pegio.o -o testPeg -std=c++11</strike>

Comment: With the exception of changing "-std=c++11" to "-std=c++0x", it works! Thank you!!